# Clip a shapefile based on raster extent with high accuracy

Tags: raster, arcpy, shapefile, clip, accuracy

I am trying to clip a shapefile based on the extents of a smaller raster. I find the extent of the raster using this code:

```
Extents = arcpy.sa.Raster(MyRaster).extent`
```

Then, I use these lines to make a polygon out of these extents:

```
pnt_array = arcpy.Array()
pnt_array.add(Extents2.lowerLeft)
pnt_array.add(Extents.lowerRight)
pnt_array.add(Extents.upperRight)
pnt_array.add(Extents.upperLeft)
poly = arcpy.Polygon(pnt_array)
```

Finally, I cut clip my shapefile using this code

```
arcpy.Clip_analysis(shp, poly, Shp_clip)
```

The problem is that I am using accuracy in two places. Please take a look:

```
Extents.XMax =                          -86.22649016383502
poly.extent.XMax =                      -86.22650146484375
arcpy.Describe(Shp_clip).extent.XMax=   -86.22650146517043
```

Is there anyway that I can get a clipped shapefile with the extent exactly as `Extents`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the extent isn't accurate. If you have spatial analyst extension then use [IsNull](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000m8000000) to create a binary raster, [raster to polygon](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000008000000) (no simplify) and then [dissolve](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000005n000000) with no fields to create a clipping polygon.

Once you've got that then just clip as normal.

If you haven't got Spatial Analyst then it's a bit more tricky.

Comment: I do have spatial analyst toolbox. I am going to give it a try and will post the result.

Comment: Your method works great. Though, it is still not  accurate enough to the extent I want. 

Eventually, I want to convert the clipped shapefile into a 1/0 raster with the cells exactly as the raster. When I use `feature to raster`, I end up with a raster with `1635, 544` columns and rows rather than `1635, 543`. I have 1 row less although I am using the exact same cell size when using `feature to raster`!

Comment: Are you setting your snap raster to the existing raster?

Comment: What do you mean by snap raster? I am using the clipped shapefile `shp_clp` as input to make a raster out of it using this code: 
`arcpy.FeatureToRaster_conversion(shp_clp, Dummy_Int, output_raster, input_raster)` where I use cell size of `input_raster` in the code.

Comment: Snap raster is an environment setting http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001w0000000m000000 that ensures the output cells align perfectly with an existing raster. Also consider output extent environment setting, that may help.

Comment: I check the snap raster page. I am not sure how it works, but, my problem is not just alignment of raster cells. I have one more row from my input raster. Do  snap raster or output extent environments help with the different number of rows?

Comment: They might. If you set snap raster and output extent to the input raster you are more likely to get exactly the same rows and columns, the cells will start at the same point and cover the same area so logically will be the same rows and columns.

Comment: I used `arcpy.env.extent = arcpy.sa.Raster(MyRaster).extent` and `arcpy.env.snapRaster = MyRaster` before doing the whole process. It worked beautifully and like a charm.